# Cannot show html tables in php

Tags: php, html, sql, formatting, html-table

Below I'll post my code and I am going to explain my problem: The fact is that this code should show the value of every record of the query that I established, the problem is that the query is right (cause I checked it on phpMyAdmin) but the page don't show me the `<tbody>`, it show me nothing, I tried to put a single echo output with the `<td>` tag but nothing, can someone solve my problem and see the error that I have done?

```
<div class="container-fluid col-lg-6">
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-default">
            <tr>
            <th>ID Pratica</th>
            <th>ID Utente</th>
            <th>Data Inizio</th>
            <th>Descrizione</th>
            <th>Data Stimata</th>
            <th>Stato</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php   
            $query_search_all="SELECT * FROM `pratiche`";
            $result = mysql_query($query_search_all);
            while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            echo "<td>".$row['id_pratica']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['id_utente']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['data_inizio']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['descrzione']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['data_stimata']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['stato']."</td>";

            }
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you check what is in `$result` ? I think it is not a resource as expected but false. It would mean your connection to the DB is not properly done

Comment: If you just start learning php, please learn about mysqli or pdo. Mysql is now deprecated.

Comment: After you get this problem solved, you're going to need to add some <tr> ... </tr> output to your loop.

Comment: @Rishi It has even been deleted in newest version of PHP :-)

Comment: @Julqas that's probably the OPs problem then - `PHP` doesn't understand it so there is no output

Comment: @CalvT It can be the reason you're right, @Trank can you first check the value in $result by var_dumping it for example, then if it is a resource, try to change `mysql_query` to `mysqli_query` instead, and change `mysql_fetch_array` to `mysqli_fetch_array` ?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `<tr>` tag.

```
<div class="container-fluid col-lg-6">
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-default">
            <tr>
            <th>ID Pratica</th>
            <th>ID Utente</th>
            <th>Data Inizio</th>
            <th>Descrizione</th>
            <th>Data Stimata</th>
            <th>Stato</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
                $query_search_all="SELECT * FROM `pratiche`";
                $result = mysql_query($query_search_all);
                while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['id_pratica']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['id_utente']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['data_inizio']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['descrzione']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['data_stimata']."</td>";
                    echo "<td>".$row['stato']."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";    
                }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: The `<tr>` should be in the loop.

Comment: However, I'm not sure if this solves the problem. Even with invalid HTML most browsers should render *something*, but it seems the OP says nothing is shown at all.

Comment: the <tr> tag is in the while loop, i tried to put the <tbody> tag in the loop but it doeasnt work the same....

Comment: The `<tr>` tag in the while loop will allow you to have multiple rows (one row per 6 table cells, or `<td>`). You should not put `<tbody>` in the loop as you do not want multiple `<tbody>`'s being printed to the html.

Comment: so why it dowasnt work? it could be maybe cause i am using bootstrap? and i have to put some sort of classes on my tr tag?

Comment: That very well could be it. You should remove bootstrap, along with any other css file, and strip it down as much as you can until you get it working. Then, add one thing back at a time. If it is still not working, hardcode data in that loop and see if it prints. Use var_dump to have certain variables print and certain points in the program, etc.

Comment: @Trank look at answers up there : What is your PHP version? And secondly, check what is in $result ? I think it is not a resource as expected but false. It would mean your connection to the DB is not properly done.

Comment: @Julqas i am not so confident with this, how can i check my php version?
I tried to change the method to put in $result the query result:
"mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 6 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )"
this is the result, and its true, then i started searching some other types and i have seen people using mysqli_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_fetch_assoc, i used the new one and it worked well.
Thanks for all the help and sorry for for bothering you.

Comment: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Answer (score -1):

Can you please check the following code???

```
<?php   
        $query_search_all="SELECT * FROM pratiche ";
        $result = mysql_query($query_search_all);
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['id_pratica']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['id_utente']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['data_inizio']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['descrzione']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['data_stimata']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['stato']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: *Why* should he "check the following code"? What's different about it? How have you solved the problem?

Comment: The single quotation of the table name **pratiche** is not same as the usual quotation as far I know @Mike :) :)

Comment: @Sakil You know that it changes nothing at all from MySQL PoV right .. ?

Comment: @Sakil Those aren't single quotes in the question, those are backticks, which is what should be used around mysql table and column names that contain reserved words or other invalid characters.

Comment: tnks for your information @mike.besides the <tr> tag was missing those I added and I didn't see the previous answer already added that. :) :)

Comment: i tried it out, but it show me nothing as before...there some other possibilieties to show tables contnent with other php scripts?

Comment: @trank i have tested your code in my computer using my database table and it works like a cham bro. I just add a <tr> tag.of course without the <tr> tag it's fine too. can you please double check your database table?

Comment: @Sakil i solved it, i don't know why and what's the difference but writing "mysql_fetch_array" is not the same as writing "mysqli_fetch_array", i just wrote it wrong, probably my version of php is on old.

Comment: @Sakil thanks man, i can not even remember how many times this things happened to me back when i was learning c++, it seems like i have returned to the first high school year.

Comment: hahahahaha @Trank sometimes I don't even find out why I am shown some errors.and errors are quiet peculiar though. :) :)